# Fake time on Ubuntu Vagrant-box to test recurring payments

Tags: php, ubuntu, vagrant, recurring, faker

I have a task to trigger failed payments every 24 hours for 7 days then if no charges account should be cancelled, i am using
a statemachine to implement such functionality.
I finished implementing the logic, howver when it comes to test it i found it is not easy as i have to wait 24 hours for 7 days to enssure
that everything is working as expected.
So, my question is is there a way to fake time, by moving it forward and back, which should fake that time for the server and each software installed
such as Postgress DB nginx etc.

I am using Vagrant and ubnutu 14.04 box as a host

Answer (score 0):

I found couple of ways to fake date & time on server:

https://www.linux.com/news/changing-what-time-process-thinks-it-libfaketime

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/datefudge.1.html